# ElasticSearch and index strategy

Tags: iis, logging, elasticsearch, kibana

We are currently setting up an ELK stack to consume our various logs. Currently we are just using an index per day and only have logs from various applications we develop (approx 100m docs). Next step is to look at other types of logs from e.g. IIS, event logs from network devices (nlb) and maybe post processed documents into statistical data. So the question is now what kind of index strategy we should use.

1. In terms of post processing of documents into statistical data, my initial idea is to create a single index (maybe per year/month depending on amount of data) per application. Makes sense?
2. In regards to IIS logs and various events logs, we could just append to the daily applications logs (currently 20k logs per day). However I'm not sure mixing logs types is a good idea, although easier to maintain. Another strategy is to create indivisual indexes for different log types (application, iis, event logs).

Any recommendations or references to good blog posts/info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend different ES Types for different log types.  Structured logging is important, you'll want to query IIS logs differently from Elmah errors log for instance.  You also may want to change the indexing settings of a particular field to make it not_analyzed.

You could keep everything in the same rolling daily/weekly/monthly index and keep them separate by type.  Something like this for a daily index example:

```
PUT 20150227

PUT 20150227/iis/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "value1": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}

PUT 20150227/errors/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "value2": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```